# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) crash report from Apple App Store.

Tags: ios, crash, store

The following crash report comes from Apple App Store.
1.What does EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) mean? Does any guy set breakpoint for my app in store? Confusing.
2.Search in google and some guys explain such kind of crash is related with block usage in your application, but this phone's os is v5.1 > 4.0, should support block.

Any idea or discussion please let me know, thank you.

```
Incident Identifier: 93450CAC-9D03-4222-9856-99425F2FFAF7
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,3
Process:         NavigatorFree [9192]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C2340283-ADE0-4737-8D15-    2D3E7FF11414/NavigatorFree.app/NavigatorFree
Identifier:      NavigatorFree
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-14 18:26:25.944 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0x0000defe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x321b1094 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 0
1   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x321b10ae gpus_KillClient
2   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x321b15ba gpusSubmitDMABuffers
3   IMGSGX535GLDriver               0x361b99b8 SubmitPacketsIfAny
4   IMGSGX535GLDriver               0x361b9ad0 glrFlushContextToken
5   GLEngine                        0x3776dc4a gliPresentViewES
6   OpenGLES                        0x380686b4 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:]
7   NavigatorFree                   0x0004a8aa -[OGLViewController touchesBegan:] (OGLViewController.m:290)
8   QuartzCore                      0x34b8b868 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)
9   QuartzCore                      0x34b8b7be CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*)
10  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x311b3ffa IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc
11  IOKit                           0x3537b606 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage
12  CoreFoundation                  0x338a8f0c __CFMachPortPerform
13  CoreFoundation                  0x338b351c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
14  CoreFoundation                  0x338b34be __CFRunLoopDoSource1
15  CoreFoundation                  0x338b230c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3383549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17  CoreFoundation                  0x33835366 CFRunLoopRunInMode
18  GraphicsServices                0x36be9432 GSEventRunModal
19  UIKit                           0x32ba2e76 UIApplicationMain
20  NavigatorFree                   0x00077a4a -[TnMaitaiAgent directionsFrom:To:] (TnMaitaiAgent.m:48)
21  NavigatorFree                   0x00003670 __48+[TnInAppPurchaseAgent sharedInAppPurchaseAgent]_block_invoke_0 (TnInAppPurchaseAgent.m:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause is that OpenGL engine still keep update even when its top view isn't visible, ios doesn't allow it.